# What's the meaning of "pi" in the autofac documentation?

Tags: c#, lambda, autofac

When reading the documentation of *autofac* we can see examples like this:

```
new ResolvedParameter(
       (pi, ctx) => pi.ParameterType == typeof(ISender),
       (pi, ctx) => ctx.Resolve<PostalServiceSender>()));
```

I know that ***ctx*** stands for ***context*** but ***pi*** ? *Parameter I...*?

Comment: Probably ParameterInfo

Comment: `ParameterInfo` (you should probably delete the question before somebody turns this into an answer).

Comment: https://autofac.org/apidoc/html/D66FE0DF.htm

Comment: MSDN: [ParameterInfo Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t2czes9w)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The documentation states that [the `ResolvedParameter` constructor](https://autofac.org/apidoc/html/D66FE0DF.htm) takes two `Func` instances:

```
public ResolvedParameter(
    Func<ParameterInfo, IComponentContext, bool> predicate,
    Func<ParameterInfo, IComponentContext, Object> valueAccessor
)
```

The `(pi, ctx) =>` is the lambda for the first parameter. In `pi`, you receive the [`ParameterInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.parameterinfo?view=netframework-4.7.1) instance from the caller for that func.